# How to get the file of a published phylogeny of a taxon

Tags: phylogenetics

If an article has a published phylogeny, is it common to get the newick file with branch lengths from the authors? In order to do further research with the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the R script related to this article. rotl: an R package to interact with the Open Tree of Life data
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12593/full

```
install.packages("rotl")
library(rotl)
studies <- studies_find_studies(property = "ot:focalCladeOTTTaxonName", 
                                    value = "Caesalpinieae", exact = TRUE)
tree <- get_study_tree(study_id = studies[["study_ids"]][1],
                           tree_id = strsplit(studies[["tree_ids"]],", ")[[1]][1])

# Example 2
cat_studies <- studies_find_studies(property = "ot:focalCladeOTTTaxonName", 
value = "Felidae", exact = TRUE)
cat_tree <- get_study_tree(study_id = cat_studies[["study_ids"]][1],
tree_id = cat_studies[["tree_ids"]][1])
cat_tree
##
## Phylogenetic tree with 38 tips and 37 internal nodes.
##
## Tip labels:
## Neofelis_nebulosa, Panthera_tigris, Panthera_uncia, Panthera_pardus, ...
##
## Rooted; includes branch lengths.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is standard practice for authors to publish their trees on [TreeBase](https://treebase.org/treebase-web/home.html) for other people to use. They'll usually list the link in the supplementary material of the paper. Some journals made this a requirement for authors.

Comment: @Ferroao I'm not sure what you mean, most of the trees on TreeBase have branch lengths

Comment: I haven't seen much with branch lengths, as the ones i needed